# Facebook App permissions do not work

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I have using Codeigniter and the Facebook SDK to have my users use the Facebook login on my Website. Works all great! But now I want to ask for permission to get the user's email address. So I added "email" to the permissions in the app settings. But when I connect to Facebook it does not ask for the persmission. Does anyone have an idea what I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

[image: Permissions]

[image: What I get]

Answer (score 1):

The permissions will be effective if you add them in the **code**, not in the App Settings (since, it is used for the App Center only).

To add in the code , you have to add a parameter **scope** with the **login** code.

If you are using Javascript SDK- [FB.Login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/)
If you are using PHP SDK- [facebook-getLoginUrl](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getLoginUrl/)

Good luck!